# Swift Timer doesn't work on Linux. Works on macOS

Tags: swift, vapor

I noticed an issue with Swift's `Timer`, and I'm not sure if this is a Swift problem, a problem with a library I'm using, or a problem with my code. I have the following Timer:

```swift
var updateTimestampTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 15, repeats: true) { timer in
     print("updating timer")
     self.updateTimestamp()
}
RunLoop.main.add(updateTimestampTimer, forMode: .common)
```

When I run the code on macOS, I get the expected output ("updating timer" printed to the console every 15 seconds), but when I run it on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04), nothing is printed to the console. I'm also experiencing this issue with `Timer.scheduledTimer` and `DispatchSource.makeTimerSource`. Here's the full code, **none of the three timers I created are firing**:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let removalTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 120, repeats: true) { timer in
                if self.users.isEmpty {
                    self.group.connectedMembers = []
                    self.readyToRemove = true
                }
                self.updateGroup()
            }
            RunLoop.main.add(removalTimer, forMode: .common)
            print("creating timestamptimer")
            var timestampTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
                if self.group.playbackState != nil {
                    if self.group.playbackState!.state == .play {
                        self.group.playbackState!.timestamp += 1
                        print(self.group.playbackState?.timestamp)
                        if self.group.playbackState!.timestamp >= self.group.currentlyPlaying!.duration {
                            //next song
                            self.group.playbackState!.timestamp = 0
                            self.nextSong(sentBy: SQUser(id: "0", username: "dfsfdsfg"))
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        print("paused")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("playback state nil")
                    
                }
            }
            RunLoop.main.add(timestampTimer, forMode: .common)
            var updateTimestampTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 15, repeats: true) { timer in
                self.updateTimestamp()
            }
            RunLoop.main.add(updateTimestampTimer, forMode: .common)
            print("created tiemstamptitmer")
        }
```

Here is a list of packages I'm using:

- Vapor v4.89.0
- Fluent v4.0.0 (paired with FluentSQLiteDriver v4.0.0)
- Leaf v4.0.0

I tried using the `Jobs` package as an alternative, and it **did fire**, but it also seemed to crash the server with error **Illegal Instruction**, so that gets us nowhere.

The server is running Swift version 5.10 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with 1 CPU Core, 25 GB Storage, 1 GB RAM (from Linode)

Comment: I would persevere with (scheduled) Jobs. I use them in a couple of applications and they are 100% reliable. If you edit/replace this question with the one that asks about solving the illegal instruction, I will try to help with that. I've been using Vapor since V2 and never needed to know anything about RunLoop!